# octagonal number theorem $q$-Pochhammer symbol expression

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, q-series

Setting the exponents of this analogue of the series in [Euler's Pentagonal Number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) to be the [octagonal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number):
$$U(q)= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{n}q^{n(6n-4)/2}$$

in [mpmath](http://mpmath.org):

```
>>> def oct(q):
...     return nsum(lambda n: ((-1)**n)* q**((6*n*n+4*n)/2), [-inf,inf])
... 
>>> taylor(lambda q: 1/oct(q), 0,30)
[mpf('1.0'), mpf('1.0'), mpf('1.0'), mpf('1.0'), mpf('1.0'), mpf('2.0'),        
mpf('3.0'), mpf('4.0'), mpf('4.0'), mpf('4.0'), mpf('5.0'), mpf('7.0'),    
mpf('10.0'), mpf('12.0'), mpf('13.0'), mpf('14.0'), mpf('16.0'), mpf('21.0'), 
mpf('27.0'), mpf('32.0'), mpf('35.0'), mpf('38.0'), mpf('44.0'), 
mpf('53.999999999999993'), mpf('67.0'), mpf('78.0'), 
mpf('85.999999999999986'), mpf('94.0'), mpf('107.0'), mpf('128.0'), 
mpf('153.0')]
```

Okay, that's easily *[oeis:A195848: Expansion of 1 / (psi(x) * chi(-x)) in powers of x where psi(), chi() are Ramanujan theta functions.](http://oeis.org/A195848)*, so I thought, let me test that:

Using the [definitions for the Ramanujan theta functions on mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanThetaFunctions.html), $\psi(q)=(-q;q)_{\infty}(q^{2};q^{2})_{\infty}$ and $\chi(q)=(-q,q^{2})_{\infty}$

```
>>> def psi(q):
...     return qp(-q,q)*qp(q*q,q*q)
... 
>>> def chi(q):
...     return qp(-q,q*q)
... 

>>> taylor(lambda q: 1/psi(q)*chi(-q), 0,30)
[mpf('1.0'), mpf('-2.0'), mpf('2.0'), mpf('-4.0'), mpf('7.0'), mpf('-10.0'),     
mpf('14.0'), mpf('-20.0'), mpf('30.0'), mpf('-42.0'), mpf('56.0'), 
mpf('-76.0'), mpf('105.0'), mpf('-140.0'), mpf('182.0'), mpf('-240.0'),  
mpf('317.0'), mpf('-410.0'), mpf('524.0'), mpf('-672.0'), mpf('861.0'), 
mpf('-1092.0'), mpf('1372.0000000000002'), mpf('-1723.9999999999998'),   
mpf('2167.0'), mpf('-2702.0'), mpf('3346.0'), mpf('-4144.0'), mpf('5125.0'), 
mpf('-6302.0'), mpf('7716.0')]
```

But those absolute values of those correspond to   *[A058630:McKay-Thompson series of class 32B for the Monster group.](http://oeis.org/A058630)*, not to $1/U(q)$!

What's the correct expression for $1/U(q)$ in terms of $q$-Pochhammer symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have parenthesized your `psi(q)*chi(-q)`, but that would not yield a match either,
as $\psi(q)\,\chi(-q) = (q^2,q^2)_\infty$ whose reciprocal just generates partition numbers (at even index values).

But Michael Somos' formula works: The series can be given as
$$\frac{(q^2,q^2)_\infty(q^3,q^3)_\infty}{(q,q)_\infty(q^6,q^6)_\infty^2}
= \frac{1}{\psi(q^3)\,\chi(-q)}$$
So you have found a typo in the title of [A195848](http://oeis.org/A195848).
It should read

> Expansion of 1/(psi(x^3) * chi(-x)) in powers of x where psi(), chi() are Ramanujan theta functions.

Feel free to report that typo.

**Update**: The title of [A195848](http://oeis.org/A195848) has been corrected.